# SharePoint - DateTimeControl does not exist in the namespace?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, share, developer

**I am getting the following error:**

> The type or namespace name DateTimeControl does not exist in the
>   namespace Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)

```
**VIEW**
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">StartDate <span class="ms-error">*</span></td>
        <td>
            <spuc:DateTimeControl ID="dtStartdate" runat="server" DateOnly="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>


**C#**

    itemToAdd["StartDate"] = dtStartdate.SelectedDate;
```

[image]

**What could be the issue?**

Comment: Please tell me another way to solve the problem ... [why is not this way](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/datetimecontrol-control/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your solution is sandbox solution then "DateTimeControl" will not support. Because "DateTimeControl" is exist in "Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" namespace. And According to microsoft, All of the control classes in the Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls namespace is not supported in sandbox solution.

[Read This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615454%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

You have two options for make it work,

1. [Use sandbox proxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798427.aspx) within your sandbox solution. (Sandbox proxies are components that enable you to make full-trust functionality available to sandboxed solutions)

   OR
2. Make it farm solution by setting the project's "Sandboxed Solution" property to false.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135597/microsoft-sharepoint-webcontrols-spribbon-not-working-in-sharepoint-sandbox-solu)

[image]

click on "test" and press F4. it will open property window. there is property named "sandbox solution". set this to false.

Comment: The data do not suffice to solve the problem.

Comment: your solution is sandbox solution or farm solution?

Comment: SharePoint Visual Web Part

Comment: to implement, a date so there things I need to do? :(

Comment: Are you added "using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;" namespace in your AddEmpWebpart.ascx.cs file?

Comment: Look lower post !

Comment: Are you added "spuc" directive in .ascx file? if NOT then add this "<%@ Register TagPrefix="spuc" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>"

Comment: "spuc" is added in my .ascs file...

Comment: Look lower... Problem come in ascx.g.cs..

Comment: your project's "sandbox solution property" is true or false?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a beginner, where I check sandbox set to true/false?

Comment: In Solution Explorer, Right click on your solution and click on properties. In property window there is property named "sandbox solution" set this to false.

Comment: Please send me "PrintScreen" :)

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: OKAY, i trying :)

Comment: click on your solution (second level) and press F4. it will open property window. there is property named "sandbox solution". set this to false.

Comment: I set sandbox solution". set this to false.

Comment: Problem is : 


Web Part Error: The request could not be completed because the specified solution was not found. Correlation ID: b377689d-bd60-d03a-2eaa-ef8bdccf8867.

Show Error Details 






Web Part Error: The request could not be completed because the specified solution was not found. Correlation ID: b377689d-bd60-d03a-2eaa-ef8bdccf8867.

Show Error Details

Comment: Now rebuild your solution. Error should be gone.

Comment: not obtained with rebuild my solution....

Comment: When you getting this error. while deploying?

Comment: When he returned to "sandbox solution" to true... no problem..

Comment: YES while deploying !

Comment: When he returned to "sandbox solution" to FALSE ----> Give me Error of all project.... Look lower...

Comment: Please Help me to solve this problem :{

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36960/discussion-on-answer-by-vishal-m-patil-sharepoint-datetimecontrol-does-not-ex).